# The way to describe something

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, passive-voice

I have drafted an idea in different ways. For this type of case, is there any rule of thumb to be followed?

> 1. For each intersecting pair of polygons, break lines are extracted.
> 2. Break lines are extracted for each intersecting pair of planar polygons.
> 3. Extraction of break lines for intersecting pair of planar polygons are done.
> 4. Break line extraction on intersecting pair of planar polygons are done.

It will be better if someone can tell me the correct way and what the errors of the incorrect ways are, because that will help me learn.

Comment: Simpler is better. Use standard sentence structure.  I.e., (2) is the best wording of the four.  Don't like the "*are done*" of numbers 3 and 4- subject verb agreement is wrong.  (1) delays the action and makes the reader wonder until the sentence is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most writing texts will tell you that the most important idea in the sentence should come at the beginning or at the end. The differences between your first two and second two sentences is **focus**. By **fronting** *For each intersecting pair of polygons,* in the first sentence, you're telling the reader that this is the important information.

There is no context for the sentence, so it's not really possible to say which is the best syntax.

Perhaps it would be better to say **have been** in sentences 1 and 2 instead of **are**, and it's definitely necessary to say **has been** or **is** or **was** in sentences 3 and 4 (they're grammatically incorrect as they stand).

Sentences 3 and 4 seem the least desirable because the syntax is a bit stilted. They should probably read like this:

> Extraction of the break lines for the intersecting pair of planar polygons has been done.
>   Break line extraction for the intersecting pair of planar polygons has been done.

or

> The break lines for the intersecting pair of planar polygons have been extracted.
>   Break lines for the intersecting pair of planar polygons have been extracted.

I prefer the last two to the previous two because they both use one specific verb (*extracted*) instead of turning the verb into a noun (*extraction*) and then adding a vague and unnecessary verb (*done*). Sentences 1 and 2 also use only one specific verb.

Comment: Yes! Yes! Resist the encroaching nominal hegemonists and their class-traitor verbal running dogs *do*, *make* and *perform*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are describing steps in a process, then present tense, not past, is appropriate.

Of the four examples, I regard only the first as acceptable, but for clarity might add the words *a set of*:

> For each intersecting pair of polygons,  a set of break lines is constructed.

The second example is almost acceptable, but the important words *pair* and  *polygons* are farther from the verb than is desirable.  Consider rewriting it as

> Break lines are extracted for each pair of polygons that intersect
>   *or*
>   Break lines are extracted wherever polygons intersect.

The passive wording of forms 3 and 4 is reason to discard them.   Note, in forms 3 and 4,  “intersecting pair of planar polygons are done” should instead be  “intersecting pairs of planar polygons is done”; that is, extraction *is* done for each pair among multiple *pairs*.